# How to use Rails and Paperclip to store photos on Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, google-cloud-storage

Until now, I have been using Amazon S3 for storing users' files.

All what has been needed to do here was:

1. specify Amazon S3 credentials to the bucket
2. add `'aws-sdk'` gem to the Gemfile
3. and in the model:

---

```
  has_attached_file :avatar, 
                    :styles => { :big => "100x100#", :thumb => "25x25#" },
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                    :url => "/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

To set the Amazon S3 adapter. That was all.

But how to set up Google cloud engine? So far I found only the [fog gem](http://fog.io/storage/) , which I could use.

However, how should I configure the model to automatically store all uploaded files on Google servers?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ok, so I made it work this way:

**Gemfile:**

```
gem 'fog'
```

**config/gce.yml:**

```
development:
  provider: Google
  google_storage_access_key_id: XXX
  google_storage_secret_access_key: XXX
```

**model:**

```
  has_attached_file :avatar, 
                    :styles => { :big => "100x100#", :thumb => "25x25#" },
                    :storage => :fog,
                    :fog_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/gce.yml",
                    :fog_directory => "your bucket name",
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                    :url => "/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

Comment: For anyone wondering how to get the keys: http://fog.io/storage/#google-cloud-storage

Comment: @user984621, I tried your solution, it works locally on dev environment, however, it might fail when you deploy it over to Heroku if you don't have the root setup correctly. For future "stackoverflow" users, try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33111528/heroku-argumenterror-is-not-a-recognized-provider/33114674#33114674, if the above solution doesn't work

Comment: I have some problems with paperclip and google cloud storage http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36240872/paperclip-validation-issue-on-production  can you help me please ? :(

Answer (score 0):

For Rails > 5.2, [Active Storage](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html) is available. The docs are a great place to start with.

In **config/environments/production.rb** :

```
# Store files on Google cloud storage.
config.active_storage.service = :google
```

In **config/storage.yml** :

```
google:
  service: GCS
  credentials: <%= Rails.root.join("path/to/keyfile.json") %>
  project: ""
  bucket: ""
```

In your User Model :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :avatar
end
```

Comment: For information this is for ActiveStorage and not for Paperclip.