# Heroku ArgumentError ( is not a recognized provider)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paperclip, fog

I am trying to upload profile pictures to Google Cloud using Paperclip and Fog gems. so far this what I have

In my Gemfile

```
gem "paperclip", git: "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
gem 'fog'
```

In my user model

```
has_attached_file   :avatar,
                      styles: {:big => "200x200>", thumb: "50x50>"},
                      storage: :fog,
                      fog_credentials: "#{Rails.root}/config/gce.yml",
                      fog_directory: "google-bucket-name"

  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

When I run this locally, I am able to upload it fine over to google. However, when I try to do this on Heroku, I am getting this error

```
015-10-13T19:47:15.703642+00:00 app[web.1]:   SQL (2.1ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "avatar_file_name" = $1, "avatar_content_type" = $2, "avatar_file_size" = $3, "avatar_updated_at" = $4, "updated_at" = $5 WHERE "users"."id" = $6  [["avatar_file_name", "3.jpeg"], ["avatar_content_type", "image/jpeg"], ["avatar_file_size", 8587], ["avatar_updated_at", "2015-10-13 19:47:15.140362"], ["updated_at", "2015-10-13 19:47:15.695467"], ["id", 3]]
2015-10-13T19:47:15.707684+00:00 app[web.1]:    (0.9ms)  ROLLBACK
2015-10-13T19:47:15.711451+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2015-10-13T19:47:15.711260 #3] FATAL -- :
2015-10-13T19:47:15.711457+00:00 app[web.1]: ArgumentError ( is not a recognized provider):
2015-10-13T19:47:15.711459+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/fog-core-1.32.1/lib/fog/core/services_mixin.rb:12:in `new'
2015-10-13T19:47:15.711461+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/fog-core-1.32.1/lib/fog/storage.rb:22:in `new'
2015-10-13T19:47:15.711463+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/paperclip-8339e0fce5d8/lib/paperclip/storage/fog.rb:217:in `connection'
2015-10-13T19:47:15.711465+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/paperclip-8339e0fce5d8/lib/paperclip/storage/fog.rb:227:in `directory'
2015-10-13T19:47:15.711468+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/paperclip-8339e0fce5d8/lib/paperclip/storage/fog.rb:101:in `block in flush_writes'
2015-10-13T19:47:15.711470+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/paperclip-
```

Not sure what's going on.

Comment: Is there a secret key needed for the `fog`?

Comment: It's uploading fine, when I try locally. It's only happening on Heroku

Comment: That does not answer my question...

Comment: I am not sure if a secret key is needed for the fog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of debugging, turns out my **fog_credentials** hash is not going through as expected on heroku. Instead of passing **"#{Rails.root}/config/gce.yml"**, I am doing this.

```
has_attached_file   :avatar,
                      styles: {:big => "200x200>", thumb: "50x50>"},
                      storage: :fog,
                      fog_credentials: { aws_access_key_id: '<your_access_id>'
                                         aws_secret_access_key: '<your secret>'
                                         provider: 'Google' },
                      fog_directory: "google-bucket-name"

  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

Comment: Env variables will work. That's how I set up finally.