# Paperclip validation issue on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-app-engine, paperclip, paperclip-validation

I have a Problem when I deploy my application on google cloud I get this error

> has contents that are not what they are reported to be

Locally it works fine! I already tried to using the command_path. So I really don't know what I have to do next...

This is my model

```
has_mongoid_attached_file  :image,
    :styles => { :large => "380x380!" , :medium => "240x240", :small => "120x120!" },
    :storage => :fog,
    :fog_public => true,
    :fog_directory => 'XXXX',
    :path => "images/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    :fog_credentials => {  :provider => 'Google',
                           :google_storage_access_key_id => 'XXXXX',
                           :google_storage_secret_access_key => 'XXXXX'}

  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
```

Thank you for your efforts. I hope you guys can help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay I found a result. I just created a `initializers/paperclip.rb` file

```
require 'paperclip/media_type_spoof_detector'
module Paperclip
  class MediaTypeSpoofDetector
    def spoofed?
      false
    end
  end
end
```

Right now it work's perfectly for me.

If you have problems with ImageMagick on App Engine using Rails see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36253667/imagemagick-on-goolge-cloud)

Comment: Do not know what its doing, But its working which matter and up voted your answer, can you please elaborate a little what its working on

Answer (score 5):

That issue occurs because the content-type discovered from `file` command returns empty string.
Actually system is not able to find the `file` executable so a exception is raised and empty string is returned back.
Check the code below

```
begin
    Paperclip.run("file", "-b --mime :file", :file => '/tmp/RackMultipart20160826-15649-kwvnq2.png').split(/[:;]\s+/).first
rescue Cocaine::CommandLineError
    ""
end
```

Solution:-

Add below line in you initializer file.

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = '/usr/bin'
```

Comment: Which  initializer file?

Comment: You can put a new initializer file, by name `paperclip.rb`, actually adding it to any of the existing initializer file should work.

Comment: Do I have to remove the MediaTypeSpoofDetector? And do use as well Google App Engine and rails?

Comment: Yes remove it and try this solution, do up vote my answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: @BilalReffas `/usr/bin` this path may vary on your system, so just verify it once by running the following command in the terminal,

`which file` the path which it returns must be added to `Paperclip.options[:command_path]`.

Comment: Still not working the problem is using app engine I don't have access to more information

Comment: In my case (docker `ruby:alpine` image) paperclip could not find the `file` executable but because it not installed on `alpine` by default. Huge thanks @NitinSatishSalunke

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Google Cloud can't determine MIME type of uploaded files.

You can map file extensions to types in you initializer (`application.rb`, `production.rb` or create `initializers/paperclip.rb`)

```
Paperclip.options[:content_type_mappings] = {
  :jpg => "image/jpeg",
  :png => "image/png",
  :gif => "image/gif"
}
```

But this way spoofing check won't be performed for image files.

Comment: Don't work for me I can upload the images to google cloud but only if my server running locally. I get this issue only when I deploy it remotely :/

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the party, but in working with a legacy RoR system, I ran into this issue.  The problem arose in setting the app up in Docker.  Ultimately paperclip calling imagemagick was attempting to use `file` to identify mime-type and the minimal Docker did not have it installed.  `apt-get install file` fixed it.