# ImageMagick on Google Cloud

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, image-processing, imagemagick, paperclip

I use ImageMagick on the Google Cloud Platform. I use rails and Google's App Engine Flexible Environment. So the problem is I want to upload an Image to process in more sizes. I use paperclip. 
The error is:

> Could not run the `identify` command. Please install ImageMagick.

So my question is how I can solve this issue? Uploading a Image without processing works 100%. But the issue is the processing I think. So paperclip needs ImageMagick to process the images.

The problem is I use App Engine Flexible Environment so I am not sure how to install it. I already tried it with `apt-get install imageMagick`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay really simple you need just a Dockerfile.

```
# This Dockerfile for a Ruby application was generated by gcloud.

# The base Dockerfile installs:
# * A number of packages needed by the Ruby runtime and by gems
#   commonly used in Ruby web apps (such as libsqlite3)
# * A recent version of NodeJS
# * A recent version of the standard Ruby runtime to use by default
# * The bundler and foreman gems
FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/ruby

# Install ruby 2.3.0 if not already preinstalled by the base image
RUN cd /rbenv/plugins/ruby-build && \
    git pull && \
    rbenv install -s 2.3.0 && \
    rbenv global 2.3.0 && \
    gem install -q --no-rdoc --no-ri bundler --version 1.11.2 && \
    gem install -q --no-rdoc --no-ri foreman --version 0.78.0
ENV RBENV_VERSION 2.3.0

# To install additional packages needed by your gems, uncomment
# the "RUN apt-get update" and "RUN apt-get install" lines below
# and specify your packages.
# RUN apt-get update
# RUN apt-get install imagemagick -y
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install imagemagick -y

# Install required gems.
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock /app/
RUN bundle install && rbenv rehash

# Start application on port 8080.
COPY . /app/
ENTRYPOINT bundle exec rackup -p 8080 -E production config.ru
```

After that just run `gcloud preview app deploy` and it will work for you.

Don't forget to change in your `app.yaml` `runtime: ruby` to `runtime: custom`

That's it happy coding